# NotificationListenerService sendBroadcast not working?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-broadcast

I'm trying for well over 10 hours now and I can't seem to think about anyhting else. I tried every possible example on the internet, but to no avail.

I have NotificationMonitor class extending NotificationListenerService and I wanted to send message from this service to main activity(and possible other activities and services in the future) using Intent mechanism. I post code below:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.testpackage.test">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".NotificationMonitor"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView txtView;
    private NotificationReceiver nReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        //create receiver
        nReceiver = new NotificationReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("com.testpackage.test.NOTIFICATION_MONITOR");
        registerReceiver(nReceiver,filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(nReceiver);
    }

    public void buttonClicked(View v){
        if(v.getId() == R.id.btnTestBroadcast){
            //send test intent without category
            Log.d("ActivityMain","Button clicked");
            Intent i = new Intent("com.testpackage.test.NOTIFICATION_MONITOR");
            sendBroadcast(i);
        }
    }

    class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("ActivityMain","Intent received: "+intent.getAction()+" has extra: "+intent.hasExtra("info"));
            if (intent.hasCategory("com.testpackage.test.TEST_CATEGORY")) {
                if (intent.hasExtra("info")) {
                    txtView.setText(intent.getStringExtra("info"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NotificationMonitor.java

```
public class NotificationMonitor extends NotificationListenerService {

    private NotificationMonitorReceiver receiver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        receiver = new NotificationMonitorReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("com.testpackage.test.NOTIFICATION_MONITOR");
        registerReceiver(receiver,filter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        //do something
        sendInfo("notification posted");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        //do something
        sendInfo("notification removed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onListenerConnected() {
        //service created and listener connected
        Log.d("NM","Listener connected!");
        sendInfo("listener connected");
    }

    private void sendInfo(String info) {
        Log.d("NM", "sendInfo called!");
        Intent i = new Intent("com.testpackage.test.NOTIFICATION_MONITOR");
        i.addCategory("com.testpackage.test.TEST_CATEGORY");
        i.putExtra("info", info);
        sendBroadcast(i);
    }

    class NotificationMonitorReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //no categories intents get replied
            Log.d("NM","Intent received: "+intent.getAction()+" has categories: "+(intent.getCategories()!=null));
            if (intent.getCategories() == null) {
                Intent i = new Intent("com.testpackage.test.NOTIFICATION_MONITOR");
                i.addCategory("com.testpackage.test.TEST_CATEGORY");
                sendBroadcast(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After running this app in debug mode of course I need to re-enable notification permissions, so when I do I see in logcat:

```
10-10 16:22:46.428 7330-7381/com.testpackage.test D/NM: Listener connected!
10-10 16:22:46.428 7330-7381/com.testpackage.test D/NM: sendInfo called!
```

well, I should receive broadcast in my application, shouldn't I?
After I click button:

```
10-10 16:22:57.607 7330-7330/com.testpackage.test D/ActivityMain: Button clicked
10-10 16:22:57.612 7330-7330/com.testpackage.test D/ActivityMain: Intent received: com.testpackage.test.NOTIFICATION_MONITOR has extra: false
10-10 16:22:57.619 7330-7330/com.testpackage.test D/NM: Intent received: com.testpackage.test.NOTIFICATION_MONITOR has categories: false
```

so the Intent is properly created and send from main activity, received back by the same activity and NotificationListenerService, has no categories so should get replied but nothing happens like when `sendInfo` method is called.

Please help, I have no other ideas about what might be wrong.

edit: I tested with regular services and of course Broadcasts are working just fine. Is there by chance any possibility that you just can't `sendBroadcast` from this particular extended service class?

Comment: It seems like that the `NotificationMonitorReceiver` has not be registered when you running the app initially. I wonder whether  `onListenerConnected` is called before  `onCreate`. You can add some logs in `onCreate` to check.

Comment: It cannot be called before `onCreate`, I tested it and `onCreate` logs after I click permission for the app. Then about one-two seconds later `onListenerConnected` gets called by system to notify class that it's connected to Notification Manager and can perform requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oficially, I'm a moron. Answer is: I didn't set up `Category` filter in `IntentFilter` and this is why I received zero properly sent intents from my class. So, long story short, to "fix" this mistake all one needs to do is add:

```
filter.addCategory("com.testpackage.test.TEST_CATEGORY");
```

and that's it. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: I guess many of us forgot to set up Intent filters or Category filters at some time. Don't worry, just accept the answer to get it off the "open questions" list ;)

Comment: Thank you for reminder! :)
Well, at least now I learned deeply how `Action` and `Category` works with `IntentFilter`